# Run a command on remote machine and store its output in variable on remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I want to capture number of rules of iptables that start with specific pattern in comment and then delete them. This is what I want to achieve. Here is my bash script

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" root@$ip_address << EOF
echo "Now Removing your IPTables";

#storing output in input variable
input=$(iptables -nL INPUT --line-number | grep ip.* | cut -d " " -f1 | xargs)

#converting variable into an array
arr1=($input);

#loop through each element of array
echo "length:${#arr1[@]}";
for (( i="${#arr1[@]}"-1;i >=0; i-- ));
do
    echo "$i:${arr1[$i]}"
    iptables -D INPUT $i;
done;
EOF
```

Problem is the iptables command is not being executed on the remote machine and the output shows the length of arr1 is 0. But I am sure iptables has rules with my desired pattern.

Error being shown in terminal:

```
-bash: line 9: 3: command not found
```

Adding `2>&1` in the end of command also not working:

```
input=$(iptables -nL INPUT --line-number | grep ip.* | cut -d " " -f1 | xargs 2>&1)
```

Comment: You really permit root login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: Use `<<"EOF"` instead of `<<EOF`.**

Your Here-Document will expand all variables and evaluate all subshells before the script is even sent to your ssh server.

Consider the following script:

```
ssh user@servername <<EOF
    echo "$(hostname)"
EOF
```

This will *not* print `servername` (the name of the computer you are connecting to) but the name of your localhost instead (the name of the computer you working on).

Before `ssh` is executed, the subshell `$(hostname)` is executed. The resulting string "`echo localhostname`" is then passed to `ssh` and executed on the remote server.

To fix the problem you have to escape the `$` inside the Here-Document or use a literal Here-Document:

```
ssh user@servername <<"EOF"
    echo "$(hostname)"
EOF
```

Comment: using literal Here-Document not showing error but its not storing output in input variable...But if I execute command manually in remote terminal then it shows output. What's the issue?

Comment: I need more information on what exactly is happening. Add the line `set -x` after the first `echo` and show us the full output (either add it directly to the question or leave a link to a https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: also now echo "$(hostname)" showing name of my remote machine.